# Уменьшить пинг к серверу в Китае

Tags: сеть

Есть сервер в Китае к нему пинг в среднем 450, как можно уменьшить пинг для жителей России?

Трасировка маршрута

```
1 <1 мс 1 ms 1 ms  192.168.0.1
2 1 ms 1 ms 1 ms  192.168.13.1
3 1 ms 2 ms 2 ms  217.77.212.161
4 2 ms 2 ms 2 ms  217.77.214.1
5 2 ms 2 ms 2 ms  217.77.208.249
6 70 ms 11 ms 11 ms  kyiv1-xe-11-1-0-284.ett.ua [80.93.115.97]
7 49 ms 47 ms 47 ms  213.242.109.33
8 54 ms 49 ms 49 ms  ae-5-5.ebr2.berlin1.level3.net [4.69.134.18]
9 50 ms 50 ms 47 ms  4.69.200.169
10 51 ms 51 ms 50 ms  ae-46-46.ebr1.amsterdam1.level3.net [4.69.143.201]
11 48 ms 48 ms 47 ms  ae-1-100.ebr2.amsterdam1.level3.net [4.69.141.170]
12 54 ms 55 ms 54 ms  ae-47-47.ebr2.london1.level3.net [4.69.143.78]
13 120 ms 121 ms 126 ms  ae-44-44.ebr1.newyork1.level3.net [4.69.137.78]
14 133 ms 124 ms 124 ms  ae-91-91.csw4.newyork1.level3.net [4.69.134.78]
15 122 ms 123 ms 123 ms  ae-92-92.ebr2.newyork1.level3.net [4.69.148.45]
16 196 ms 191 ms 191 ms  4.69.135.185
17 196 ms 199 ms 199 ms  ae-91-91.csw4.sanjose1.level3.net [4.69.153.14]
18 191 ms 191 ms 191 ms  ae-44-90.car4.sanjose1.level3.net [4.69.152.198]
19 198 ms  *  198 ms  china-telec.car4.sanjose1.level3.net [4.71.114.102]
20 199 ms  *  199 ms 202.97.52.229
21 363 ms 363 ms  * 202.97.50.113
22 338 ms 338 ms 338 ms 202.97.33.1
23 *  365 ms 364 ms 202.97.33.13
24 *  373 ms * 202.97.55.6
25 354 ms 354 ms 353 ms 220.191.135.98
26 357 ms * 357 ms 122.224.186.42
27 * * 381 ms  119.38.220.42
28 373 ms 374 ms * 119.38.221.13
29 * * * Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
30 * 354 ms 355 ms 223.4.131.201
```

Comment: нам нужен    traceroute -n <server host>или    tracepath -n <server host>естественно из России пускать

Comment: Закинул в тело вопроса.. в комментарий не влез)

Comment: Решение может найтись только если у Китая есть более "прямое" соединение с Россией, хотя и тут под вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

Да.. сбоку тут сетевик сидит у меня ))) говорит, что есть некий Чайна-Телеком (его видно тут на хопе 19 *china-telec.car4.sanjose1.level3.net*), который является монополистом в Китае. Так вот, внутри него происходит вот такой пипец (тут 21 хоп), что мы видим.

У меня пока решения нет, сорри )

Comment: Половина этого пинга в любом случае принадлежит предыдущим 18 хопам. Но вообще, интересная картинка: идти в Китай через Атлантику и Асашай. Кстати, ничего сверхъестественного не вижу в Китайском телекоме, задержка растет минимально. Основную задержку вносит 4.71.114.102 - 202.97.52.229, один, видимо, где-то в асашай, второй в Китае.

Comment: Предполагаю, что на работу Великого Файерволла съедается время.

Answer (score 0):

А перенести в РФ или на площадку в Европе сервер - не вариант ?